# Node.js PostgreSQL requests are being terminated prematurely

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sql-update

I´m trying to perform updates on a PostgreSQL db using node but I´m getting an `Error: Connection terminated` performing `UPDATE` operation. I´ve probably messed up when handling the connections in a proper async way prematurely terminated them but can´t wrap my head on how I could perform that correctly.

Sorry for the big lump of code but it is pretty straightforward.

```
//main.js
var result = require('./processes.js');
result.check(function(message) {
    console.log(message);

});

result.decrease(); //Throws an error.


//workers.js
var pg = require ('pg');
var fs = require('fs');

var db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../config.json', 'utf8')).db;
var querydb = require('./querydb.js');

var self = module.exports = {
    check: function(callback) {
        querydb.select("SELECT size FROM workers WHERE id = 1", function(results) {
            callback(results[0].size);
        });
    },
    increase: function() {
        self.check(function(workers) {
            querydb.update("UPDATE workers SET size = " + (workers + 1) + " WHERE id = 1");
        });
    },
    decrease: function() {
        self.check(function(workers) {
            querydb.update("UPDATE workers SET size = " + (workers - 1) + " WHERE id = 1");
        });
    }
};


//querydb.js
var pg = require ('pg');
var fs = require('fs');

var db = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../config.json', 'utf8')).db;

var select = function(statement, callback) {
    pg.connect(db, function(err, client, done) {
        var results = [];
        //Handle errors
        if(err) {
            done();
            console.log(err);
        }
        var query = client.query(statement);

        //Stream results back
        query.on('row', function(row) {
            results.push(row);
        });

        //When all data is returned.
        query.on('end', function() {
            done();
            callback(results);
            client.end();
        });
    });
}

var update = function(statement) {
    pg.connect(db, function(err, client, done) {
        var results = [];
        //Handle errors
        if(err) {
            done();
            console.log(err);
        }
        var query = client.query(statement);

        //When all data is returned.
        query.on('end', function() {
            done();
            client.end();
        });
    });
}

module.exports = {
    select: select,
    update: update
};
```

Comment: If you were to use [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) instead, you wouldn't have had that headache with the connections, as they would be handled automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this maybe isn´t an answer *per se* and more of a workaround but having synchronous calls for this kind of script (i.e. not a web server) was the desired behavior I wanted so I ended up going with [pg-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-native) instead of pg and refactored my `querydb` and `workers` modules to use it and now everything works!